# Pass byte numpy array to C function using ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to pass byte numpy array to a `C` function using `ctypes`. The `C` function takes `void *mem_address` so I thought to pass it as the following:

```
lst = np.random.choice(np.array(range(0, 100), dtype=np.int), size=(100, 5))
lst = np.asarray(lst).tobytes()

# Pass
lst.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)
```

This gives the error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'ctypes'` which means `ctypes` does not handle numpy. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lst = np.asarray(lst).tobytes()` generates a plain *Bytes* object ([[Python.Docs]: class bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) which is not handled by *CTypes*.

The original object (*lst*) on the other hand ([[NumPy]: numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)), is.
So, removing the above line of code, would fix the error.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 1):

`lst` is now a python `bytes` object, not a `numpy` array. Thats what `.tobytes()` does.

Why not do

```
lst = np.random.choice(np.array(range(0, 100), dtype=np.int), size=(100, 5))
lst.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)
```

?

I'm not even sure why you tried to convert to a byte which is 8 bit when c pointers are 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the fact that  c pointers are 32 or 64 bit.